# exportar mi .php a pdf

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

Actualmente lo estaba haciendo con DOMPDF, con php 5.3 , pero migre a un php 5.1 y DOMPDF no es compatible con esa versión de php.

necesito saber si existe alguna otra librería que me permita exportar mi .php de forma sencilla como lo hacia con DOMPDF sin estar escribiendo cada fragmento como lo es con fpdf :(

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que uses [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/). Recientemente usé esta librería para generar certificados de cumplimiento y me fue bien. Ellos tienen un [ejemplo](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_006/) que utiliza el método `WriteHTML()` y consiste en pasar un `HTML` y lo imprime en el documento `pdf`.

Comment: @pedro-e-palau con esta librería que me indicas, debo prácticamente programar todo el estilo y formato html nuevamente, siendo que mi PHP ya tiene su estilo y formato propio, con DOMPDF  no debía programar todo lo que va dentro de mi PDF :(

Comment: Hola revisa el ejemplo https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_006/

Comment: debe haber algo mejor, en la cual no debas configurar  tanto :(

Answer (score 0):

Con esa versión de PHP no creo que tengas muchas opciones, si tienes acceso a una linea de comando puedes intentar instalar [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) y hacer un script que ejecute las opciones que necesites. Utilizarlo es tan fácil como

```
wkhtmltopdf http://google.com google.pdf
```

Comment: lo probare y te comento

Comment: finalmente logre con dompdf version 6.1 habilitando el parseo y modulo curl